# Network Bandwidth IBM SOFTLAYER CLOUD

Tags: ibm-cloud

What is the best way to capture the monthly network bandwidth( ingress\ egress) or outbound and inbound public traffic. Do I select individual devices to get bandwidth used. Or do I select my vyatta device only as everything should pass through that for public traffic to and from internet?

Also- what options do I have to see what servers specifically are passing public traffic across the internet? Are there any dashboard tools \ API's available for this?